# How to use a different controller in WebApiConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, asp.net-web-api2

I'm attempting to use a more modular design with my WebApiConfig where i can set routes and reference other controllers. However I can't seem to find anything that really works.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Web.Http;
using ASCI.ConstantsStrorage;

namespace DashBoard.API
{
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        // Routing for email service 
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "EmailApiRoute",
            routeTemplate: Constants.BaseEndPointV1 + "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ASCIEmailController" }
        );
        //routing for accessing different fields 
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "FieldsApiRoute",
                routeTemplate: Constants.BaseEndPointV1 + "{controller}/{name}/field/{fieldName}/{data}",
                defaults: new{
                        name = RouteParameter.Optional,
                        fieldName = RouteParameter.Optional,
                        data = RouteParameter.Optional
                }
        );          
        //default routing for raw dashboard objects  
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: Constants.BaseEndPointV1 + "{controller}/{name}",
            defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        // allows for json to be the default response type, but still allows you to specify different response types (i.e XML) 
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings
        .Add(new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept",
                            "text/html",
                            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase,
                            true,
                            "application/json")
            );
    }
}
}
```

as you can see i tried setting controller to a different controller which is below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using ASCI.ETW_Tracing;
using ASCI.ConstantsStrorage;

namespace DashBoard.API.Controllers
{
    public class ASCIEmailController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route(Constants.BaseEndPointV1 + "email")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(Models.Email))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostEmail([FromBody]Models.Email email)
        {
            // allows us to send the email
            EmailHelper emailHelper = new EmailHelper();
            Models.Email sentEmail = emailHelper.SendEmail(email);

            return CreatedAtRoute("EmailApiRoute", new { id = email.Body }, sentEmail);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't really find a way to resolve this, any help would be very much appreciated.

---

```
namespace ASCI.ConstantsStrorage
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constant that is used throughout the API for version control.
        /// Currently on version 1.0 of the API
        /// </summary>
       public const string BaseEndPointV1 = "api/v1/";
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing first , route `DefaultApi` is general mapping and that should be configured after all specific routes are mapped.

Comment: Alright i moved it down, but that doesn't really help fix the problem i'm encountering.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya do you have any other suggestions to make this work?

Comment: With this code what happens when you call your API? Also can you share the value of  Constants.BaseEndPointV1 ?  I need to replicate this issue on my machine to find a proper solution. Give me some time.

Comment: I added constants to the end of the post